# spaces with fundamental group Z/nZ

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $f : S
1 → S
1$ be a map of degree $grad(f) = n$.

Consider the space $M(n) = S
1 ∪_f D^
2$ obtained by attaching a
$2$-disc to a circle along its boundary using the map $f$ — i.e.,

the quotient $(S
1 $ $\bigcup\ D^
2
)/ ∼$ where $∼$ is the equivalence
relation generated by the relations $x ∼ f(x)$ for $x ∈ ∂D^
2 = S^
1$.

(1) Make a sketch of this identification.

(2) Show that $π_1(M(n))$ is isomorphic to $Z/nZ$.

Does anyone have any idea how this sketch should look like? For $(2)$ I was trying to use van-Kampen Theorem but then I got stuck..

Comment: Just sketch a regular $n$-gon and identify all the edges. Yes, Van Kampen is good: one set will be the neighborhood of the boundary and another the interior: then you see that $n$ times the generator is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get that this sketch is a regular n-gon? For Van Kampen I was thinking to take a point $x_0$ in the interior and then for $U$ take $M$ \ $x_0$ and for V a small ball around $x_0$, but again I get in trouble when computing the fundamental group of $U$ intersected $V$

Comment: Fundamental group of $V$ is trivial; fundamental group of $U$ is $\Bbb Z$, generated by one edge (note that $U$ deformation retracts to the boundary, which is topologically just one edge of the $n$-gon). The intersection $U\cap V$ has fundamental group also $\Bbb Z$ the generator is a "full circle" and its image in $U$ is $n$ times the generator of $U$.