# Topological space with fundamental group $\mathbb Z / 2023 \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Find a compact, path connected topological space with the fundamental group $\mathbb Z / 2023 \mathbb Z$.

I tried to create one by using a square in $\mathbb R^2$ and putting holes into it, so we would at least get the cardinality $2023$. That didn't turn out successful since I would only get even cardinalities.

I think I need to apply the Seifert-van-Kampen theorem in some way. So I would need a topological space which I can split to two open sets with a non-empty union. These two sets have fundamental groups which will push out a third group $\mathbb Z/2023 \mathbb Z$. But I'm have a really hard time dealing with push outs, so I cannot really even get this approach started. I tried to look at examples in the internet but it didn't help (I didn't find similar ones).

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130378/spaces-with-fundamental-group-z-nz) and take $n=2023$.

Comment: Here's [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191271/seifert-van-kampen-understanding) - replace $x \sim ix$ with $x \sim e^{2\pi i / 2023} x$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

We have

$\pi_1(U) = \mathbb{Z},$

$\pi_1(V) = 1,$

$\pi_1 (U \cap V) = \mathbb{Z}.$

Note that $i_* : (c) = \mathbb{Z} = \pi_1 (U \cap V) \to \pi_1(U) = \mathbb{Z} = (a)$ with $c \mapsto a^{2023}.$

Therefore, $\pi_1 (X) = (a)/(a^{2023}) = \mathbb{Z}_{2023}.$